# Loading related entities in EF Core lead to huge amounts of db trips

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I've got the following ef core model

```
        public class Person
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public Passport Passport { get; set; }
        }

        public class Passport
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Number { get; set; }
        }
```

When doing request, which is looks like:

```
            .Include(x => x.Passport)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                PersonId = x.Id,
                PassportNumber = x.Passport.Number
            })
```

I observe that for each user EF Core doing trip to database to get passport. So if persons count is 10, then 10 request will go to db for getting passport entity. Is there any way for doing 1 request instead of 10 for getting passports?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Since you're doing a select you shouldn't need the `Include` in the first place.

Comment: @juharr But event if i'm not doing select, i need to include property, that's ugly 10 requests go to db? Do you know whether n+1 problem was fixed for EF core?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code by a linq with join operation.

```
var q = from p in context.Persons
        join pa in context.Passport
        on p.PassportId equals pa.Id
        select new
        {
         PersonId = p.Id,
         PassportNumber = pa.Number
        }
```

I recommend that you add the passportId property into the Person class.